# Signing a Mac App Store app with Developer ID for test release

Tags: macos, code-signing, xcodebuild, mac-app-store, osx-gatekeeper

I've got a Mac App Store app for which I distribute ad-hoc betas using Slack. These betas rely on the Sandbox Testing environment and provisioning profiles for authentication (and that way my Mac App Store receipt validation gets tested in the beta process).

The problem I'm trying to solve is the Gatekeeper prompts when a user runs a new build of my app. I'd rather not have to explain the *just right-click it* workaround for each new user. But when I export using Developer ID instead of my "Mac Development" certificate (which successfully gets my past Gatekeeper), I get this failure at launch, and never get prompted for the sandbox testing credentials:

> StoreLegacy: Failed to perform in-line receipt renewal for application at path /path/to/my.app : '(null)'

I'm exporting from an archive with these options using `xcodebuild`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>developer-id</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>automatic</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Is it possible to sign with Developer ID and still use the Sandbox Testing environment? I filed [a radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5023637522350080) about this a couple of years ago and it was closed with the message "To get access to certain features, you need to be MAS-signed". With the prevalence of automatic signing now baked into Xcode with Xcode 8 and 9, has this situation improved at all?